# 'Image' is Type and cannot be used as an expression in vb

Tags: vb.net

What will be the exact same code of this in vb?

```
  using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
 .
 .
 .
protected virtual void CheckFavorite(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (Session["favorite"] != null) {
        if ((!string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)Session["favorite"])) && ((string)Session["favorite"] == Request.RawUrl)) {
            Image img = (Image)sender;
            img.ImageUrl = img.ImageUrl.Replace("/favoritetransparent.png", "/unfavoritetransparent.png");
        }
    }
}
```

I have made following vb code where I am getting 'Image' is Type and cannot be used as an expression error.

```
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls
.
.
.
Protected Overridable Sub CheckFavorite(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Session("favorite")) Then
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Session("favorite").ToString()) AndAlso (Session("favorite").ToString() = Request.RawUrl) Then
            Dim img As Image
            Image img = (Image)sender
            img.ImageUrl = img.ImageUrl.Replace("/favoritetransparent.png", "/unfavoritetransparent.png")
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

I am getting error on 'Image img = (Image)sender'

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Mixing in a little C# with vb code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing these lines:

```
Dim img As Image
Image img = (Image)sender
```

to this:

```
Dim img As Image = CType(sender, Image)
```